Getting *Remote* WorkItem Links from the Reporting EndPoint
One can get workitem links from the reporting endpoint:
Reporting Work Item Links
One can also hit the operations store to get information about the work items, including Remote links [such as Hyper Links, Git Links, etc.]... but hitting the operation store will introduce throttling...
Note: Get WorkItem Links with State Via REST API  is an example of hitting the operational store... and the enum for the reporting link I posted above does NOT contain the appropriate values..
I have searched the "Learn.Microsoft.com" and I have even spent a day with DotPeek and the NuGet package... Hopefully I am just missing something...

What do you mean by hitting the operation store? Did you encounter any specific error when calling that API? Would you share some screenshots and a snippet of your code to help understand your issue? Or can you specify your expectations to use that API?

@Alvin - https://{{coreServer}}/{{organization}}/{{project}}/_apis/wit/workitems is the live work item store... [maybe the terminology has changed since I was a ALM ranger pre 2018]
https://{{coreServer}}/{{organization}}/{{project}/_apis/wit/reporting/workitemlinks is indeed the reporting store, but does not return "remote" links... only (no surprise) WorkITemLinks....

Update
Based on the discussions, we can use this API instead to get those missing links.
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems?ids={ids}&$expand=Relations&api-version=7.1-preview.3

Here is a sample PowerShell task to call this request in a pipeline.
steps:
- checkout:  none
- pwsh: |
    $headers = @{
      'Authorization' = 'Bearer ' + "$(System.AccessToken)"
      'Content-Type' = 'application/json'
    }
    $URL = "$(System.CollectionUri)$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/wit/workitems?ids=2184,2185&`$expand=Relations&api-version=7.1-preview.3"
    $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $URL -Headers $headers
    $response | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100


Please also note that it returns a list of work items Maximum 200.

If the rate limit is a concern for you, you may call that API in a pipeline to authenticate against the pipeline service account using $(System.AccessToken), which, compared to PATs, is less prone to getting throttled, doesn't need manual refresh, and isn't tied to a personal account.
steps:
- checkout:  none
- pwsh: |
    $headers = @{
    'Authorization' = 'Bearer ' + "$(System.AccessToken)"
    'Content-Type' = 'application/json'
    }
    ########################################################################################################################################################
    # Call Sample API
    # Reporting Work Item Links - Get GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/reporting/workitemlinks?api-version=7.1-preview.3

    $URL = "$(System.CollectionUri)$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/wit/reporting/workitemlinks?api-version=7.1-preview.3"

    $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $URL -Headers $headers
    $response | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100
    $response | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100 | Out-File "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\WITLinks-$(System.TeamProject).json"




Thanks... but for consistency [and other reasons] I am really hoping I just overlooked an endpoint, parameter, or body element on the Reporting EndPoint.... we are talking about potentially (many) millions work items - large instances that may have history going back to TFS-2008, I have seen some work items with revision number over 10K

Zhao - I just looked closer at your example... That is returning WorkItem type links... NOT remote links [like a link to an HTTP end point, or a file share, or a Commit [or a CheckIn for TFVC or. or. or...]  --- It is that endpoint I am looking for... I am using the end point [but via the NuGet package] for getting Work Item [not Remote] links.  the giveaway is having 2 work item numbers in the response.

Hi David, Thanks a lot for your taking time to share the information I have come up with another API for your reference in the updated answer. Would you have a test with that? Hope it can help resolve your query in this post. Many thx and wish you a happy weekend.

#1) Thanks for keeping up with this, and a pleasant weekend for you also.
#2) Please don't "edit", makes it hard than having a new/different answer....
If I am following you are now suggesting using "_apis/wit/workitems", if that is the case, then that is unacceptable because of the throttling issue... The reason for going to the "_apis/wit/reporting/workitemlinks" was specifically to avoid the problems with "_apis/wit/workitems".....

What I am looking for [but have not found, may not exist] is either some parameters [like a hypothetical "expand remote links" or another endpoint like (again hypothetical "_apis/wit/reporting/remotelinks"

Yes, I can understand the limitation. However, as far as I know, I am afraid there is no such a endpoint that only reports remote links.

Zhao - Not "only" but including "remote" links from the reporting store rather than the operational store... Running into so many problems/limitations with the ReST API [just opened tickets related to git ReST endpoints and author/commiter time, but that is a different topic].  Definately feels like "second class" citizen (or worse) in therms of the things that can NOT be done - it has gotten bad enough I miss the SOAP endpoints of the original version(s).
